# Strange array test in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, each

I have noticed strange behavior.
While this one runs as expected:

```
@a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
def test2
  @a[0..2].each do |i|
    puts 'I am at: ' +i.to_s
    if i == '2'
      puts 'I am removing 2'
      @a.delete(i)
      licz
    end
  end
end


I am at: 0
I am at: 1
I am at: 2
I am removing 2
I am at: 0
I am at: 1
I am at: 3
```

Somehow, this code, 'remembers' old array and tries to finish previous 'if' statement:

```
@a = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
def test1
  @a.each do |i|
    puts 'I am at: ' +i.to_s
    if i == '2'
      puts 'I am removing 2'
      @a.delete(i)
      test1
    end
  end
end
    I am at: 0
    I am at: 1
    I am at: 2
    I am removing 2
    I am at: 0
    I am at: 1
    I am at: 3
    I am at: 4
    I am at: 5
    I am at: 4
    I am at: 5
    => ["0", "1", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Why does it repeat 4 5, 4 5 ?

I am aware that in second test, I run each on each element, but why it tries to finish old statement?

Comment: Because you're calling this method recursively.

Comment: just noticed that. lol, to much of coding for the weekend ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you call the same function (test1) twice.